# ExportToHttpResponse Crytal Report in IE10

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, internet-explorer-10

In a ASP.Net web application I've written I'm using .Net's CrystalDecisions assemblies (version 10.5) to load and populate a Crystal Report and display it to the client as a PDF.

I load my crystal report and immediately export is to an HTTP response stream as a PDF.  However, in IE10 this comes out as garble on my screen.  It works well in all other browsers and displays the PDF correctly.

Any ideas?

Export code here:

```
report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "ExportedReport");
```

Again the report loads fine in Chrome, older versions of IE but not IE10.

Answer (score 2):

```
report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport");
```

Set the `True` instead of `False`
your problem will solved.

Comment: Yes I've tried it that way and it works, but I'd prefer to be able to display the PDF inline in the browser and not as a seperate file for them to 'Open'.  Thanks